# About rotating a vector around the unit circle and its new coordinates

Tags: rotations

> Where does $\vec e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ go to? Rotate it by an angle $\theta$. Its new coordinates are $\Bigl(\cos\bigl(\theta + \frac {\pi}{2}\bigr), \sin\bigl(\theta + \frac {\pi}{2}\bigr)\Bigr)$.

Any reason we add $\frac {\pi}{2}$ to $\theta$ instead of say, $\pi$? I am just wondering why we get specifically $\Bigl(\cos\bigl(\theta + \frac {\pi}{2}\bigr), \sin\bigl(\theta + \frac {\pi}{2}\bigr)\Bigr)$ after rotating $\vec e_2$ around the unit circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\left[\begin{array}{c}\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\\ \sin\frac{\pi}{2}\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right].$$ That is, the point on the unit circle which makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with the positive real axis is $(0, 1)$. So if we rotate by an angle of $\theta$, we obtain the point $$\left[\begin{array}{c}\cos\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\ \sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: How do we the first column of the rotation matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} cos \theta \\ sin \theta \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: If $R_{\theta}$ denotes the rotation matrix, then $R_{\theta}\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$ is the first column of $R_{\theta}$. So the first column of $R_{\theta}$ is the image of $\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$ under the rotation which is $\left[\begin{array}{c}\cos\theta \\ \sin\theta\end{array}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

General formula for rotation on a plane about angle $\theta$ is given by the formula:
$$R_\theta(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &-\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\cos\theta  - y\sin\theta \\ x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$$
Which coincides with the intuiton how rotation should behave. Now when you consider point $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ then you get that $R_\theta(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} -\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}.$ Now you have to remember from school (or derive simply using complex analasis or from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity)) that $-\sin\theta=\cos(\theta+\pi/2)$ and $\cos\theta=\sin(\theta+\pi/2).$ And voila